# Efficient use of timestamps (objective-C, PHP, SQL)

Tags: php, sql, objective-c, format, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to manage time-stamps in a SQL database, which I am communicating with via PHP, and ultimately printing data in Objective-C and Java.

This is basically a two-part question, but they are related:

1) I know using `NSDateFormatter` is rather simple, but quite expensive. I'm wondering the most efficient way to go about keep track, parsing, and printing this data in a user-friendly format like so "5 days left on your timer." Should I make conversions in PHP, objective-C, or not use timestamps at all and use normal "ints" in the database?

For clarification/example, let's say from my app, I set a timer, and I want to keep track of that time in my database and a week from now,
2) I want to alert from `SQL->PHP->Objective-C that said "timer" is now complete/over`.

This is not what I will be doing in practice, but understanding how to most efficiently do this would be sufficient for me to do what I want to do. Thanks a lot for any clarification, and sorry if this subject has been covered before, but I could not find comprehensive answers!

Comment: This is really asking for opinions and is very broad, likely too  broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing your timestamp in a database; a database is read by computers not humans; converting human-readable date/time strings into the internal formats used by computers for dates often presents challenges (just search SO for all those questions asking why some date isn't parsing correctly); and you want to support Objective-C, Java and PHP... that should all lead you to an obvious answer!

Store your times as some integral type representing the number of some time unit from a fixed point, e.g. the number of microseconds since the 1st Jan 1900. To pick the unit and fixed point look at your three target languages and see what unit & fixed point they use, pick the most appropriate, and convert on read/write to the DB if needed.

Just my opinion of course, there is no right answer. HTH.